# Titanium, how to make different instances of the same window

Tags: javascript, object, titanium

so i have a file, JS file, called sub board. In this file it creates a window called subWin. I then do.

```
var windows = new array();
windows[0] = subwin;
windows[1] = subwin;
```

but when i change something in windows[0] it changes in windows[1].

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you just assigned the same reference to a window to two different variable names.  They are both referencing the same window, which is why changing one changes the other.

Try something like:

```
function createSubWin(msg){
  var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

  var myLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: msg
  });
  win.add(myLabel);
  return win;
}


var windows = new array();
windows[0] = createSubWin("Hello");
windows[1] = createSubWin("World");
```

Here these createSubWin() functions would call your code that returns a new window instance and stores it in the array you have defined.